# MongoMapper and more than one databases in application

Tags: mongomapper

Is it possible to use MongoMapper in application that stores its models in many databases? For example I have separated database for Users and another one for Orders and I want to model both User and Order using MongoMapper. Of course I can switch MongoMapper.connection attribute but it is potentially unsafe due to race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the connection per model:

`User.connection(Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017))`

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched for accessor= and I assumed that connection is read only when I didn't find it.