# Setting up mongomapper for multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

How can I have one mongo model go to one database and another using another database?

I've been send this link

https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/persistence.rb

and this stackoverflow answer is like my answer

[MongoMapper and more than one databases in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751568/mongomapper-and-more-than-one-databases-in-application)

Where in my application do I set the connection for my Models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source link you posted is what you want.  Those methods are all mixed-in to your models, so:

```
class MyModel
  include MongoMapper::Document
  connection(Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017))
  set_database_name "my_database"
  # ...
end
```

Since it's just a Mongo::Connection, you can use [any of its supported options](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Connection.html#constructor_details). ([source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/connection.rb#L45))

Comment: +1 Also worth noting that you can have have the MongoMapper.connection set in `config/initializers/mongo.rb` as per the docs and then you can just change the database for each model as appropriate, i.e. no need for the `connection(...)` line.