# MongoDB MongoMapper Ruby Replica Set Config

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

I'm using this config to connect to MongoDB with MongoMapper in my Sinatra application:

`MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)`

Now I have a replica set with 2 mongos on separate servers, 10.5.5.5, and 10.5.5.6. How do I setup the connection with both mongos? How do I add authentication to this connection?

Comment: please accept one of the answers, to mark this question for others as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

`MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::MongoReplicaSetClient.new(
    ['10.5.5.5:27017', '10.5.5.6:27017'],
    :read => :primary, :rs_name => 'name', :connect_timeout => 30, :op_timeout => 30
  )
  MongoMapper.database = "db_name"
  MongoMapper.database.authenticate("user", "test123")`

Works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a different connection [per model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538808/1279355). But I guess this is not exactly what you trying to do.

```
class MyModel
  include MongoMapper::Document
  connection(Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017))
  set_database_name "my_database"
  # ...
end
```

Or there is [ReplSetConnection](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.2.1/Mongo/ReplSetConnection.html) with this you can set your replications sets:

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::ReplicaSetConnection.new(['10.5.5.5', 30000], [' 10.5.5.6', 30000])
```

And the authentication is simple:

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "DBNAME"
MongoMapper.database.authenticate("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
```

Comment: Thanks Sir l33tname, looks almost good. I posted my solution below. I'm not sure what the RetryReplicaSetConnection is, but that might work as well.

Comment: @Vidar shit, I'm sorry, of course it's ReplicaSetConnection and not RetryReplicaSetConnection, but there is a gist for a automatic failover https://gist.github.com/bhbryant/1230938 which uses RetryReplicaSetConnection